# Two finger tap to right-click in Wayland

Tags: gnome, touchpad, wayland, libinput

*Goal:* tap touchpad with two fingers to call on right-click action

**Is it possible to configure it yet in Wayland / Weston / Gnome 3.26?**

It is really annoying when using the touchpad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install gnome-tweaks:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Run it: Meta Ajustments

Then in Keyboard and Mouse section

Change the click method to fingers.

Answer (score 0):

Working by default as of December 04, 2017